# LESS nesting multuple psuedo elements/classes not working

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to get the output:

```
#parent a:hover,
#parent a:link,
#parent a:visited {
    color: #000;
}
```

I am using this LESS:

```
#parent {
    a {
        :link, :hover, :visited {
            color: #000;
         }
    }
}
```

it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [LESS parent selector `&`](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature):

```
#parent a {
  &:link, &:hover, &:visited {
    color: #000;
  }
}
```